# Solr - Data Import Handler - Full Import - Clean=False by default?

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler, dih

Version: apache-solr-3.5.0

For full imports, you can set a url param clean=false.

However, can 'clean' be set to 'false' as a default, somewhere like the XML configs, or something?

If not, can full imports be disabled in any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the clean default value within your solrconfig.xml, in the DataImportHandler section like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">solr-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="clean">false</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration): 'invariants' means that you cannot change it later, while defaults is just a default that you can overwrite at request time.

I don't think you can disable the `full-import` since that's a command, not just a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.  If I can avoid the index getting 'cleaned', then I'm not worried about disabling 'full-import' ... whatever keeps my precious index safe [relatively] from an accidental deletion!